# Mapear um Json para uma ViewModel através do AutoMapper

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

Possuo o seguinte Json (Estou apostando apenas um pedaço dele).

```
{
"filters": {},
"competition": {
    "id": 2021,
    "area": {
        "id": 2072,
        "name": "England"
    },
    "name": "Premier League",
    "code": "PL",
    "plan": "TIER_ONE",
    "lastUpdated": "2019-05-12T20:05:45Z"
},
"season": {
    "id": 468,
    "startDate": "2019-08-10",
    "endDate": "2020-05-17",
    "currentMatchday": 1,
    "winner": null
},
"standings": [
    {
        "stage": "REGULAR_SEASON",
        "type": "TOTAL",
        "group": null,
        "table": [
            {
                "position": 1,
                "team": {
                    "id": 76,
                    "name": "Wolverhampton Wanderers FC",
                    "crestUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fc/Wolverhampton_Wanderers.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 2,
                "team": {
                    "id": 58,
                    "name": "Aston Villa FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/9/9f/Aston_Villa_logo.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 3,
                "team": {
                    "id": 64,
                    "name": "Liverpool FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/0/0a/FC_Liverpool.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 4,
                "team": {
                    "id": 65,
                    "name": "Manchester City FC",
                    "crestUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Manchester_City_FC_badge.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 5,
                "team": {
                    "id": 67,
                    "name": "Newcastle United FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/56/Newcastle_United_Logo.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 6,
                "team": {
                    "id": 57,
                    "name": "Arsenal FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/Arsenal_FC.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 7,
                "team": {
                    "id": 61,
                    "name": "Chelsea FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/5/5c/Chelsea_crest.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 8,
                "team": {
                    "id": 73,
                    "name": "Tottenham Hotspur FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/b4/Tottenham_Hotspur.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 9,
                "team": {
                    "id": 62,
                    "name": "Everton FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/f/f9/Everton_FC.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 10,
                "team": {
                    "id": 66,
                    "name": "Manchester United FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/d/da/Manchester_United_FC.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 11,
                "team": {
                    "id": 68,
                    "name": "Norwich City FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/8/8c/Norwich_City.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 12,
                "team": {
                    "id": 356,
                    "name": "Sheffield United FC",
                    "crestUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9c/Sheffield_United_FC_logo.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 13,
                "team": {
                    "id": 338,
                    "name": "Leicester City FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/63/Leicester02.png"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 14,
                "team": {
                    "id": 328,
                    "name": "Burnley FC",
                    "crestUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/02/Burnley_FC_badge.png"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 15,
                "team": {
                    "id": 563,
                    "name": "West Ham United FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/e/e0/West_Ham_United_FC.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 16,
                "team": {
                    "id": 340,
                    "name": "Southampton FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/c/c9/FC_Southampton.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 17,
                "team": {
                    "id": 354,
                    "name": "Crystal Palace FC",
                    "crestUrl": "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/b/bf/Crystal_Palace_F.C._logo_%282013%29.png"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 18,
                "team": {
                    "id": 397,
                    "name": "Brighton & Hove Albion FC",
                    "crestUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/fd/Brighton_%26_Hove_Albion_logo.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 19,
                "team": {
                    "id": 346,
                    "name": "Watford FC",
                    "crestUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/Watford.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            },
            {
                "position": 20,
                "team": {
                    "id": 1044,
                    "name": "AFC Bournemouth",
                    "crestUrl": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/4/41/Afc_bournemouth.svg"
                },
                "playedGames": 0,
                "won": 0,
                "draw": 0,
                "lost": 0,
                "points": 0,
                "goalsFor": 0,
                "goalsAgainst": 0,
                "goalDifference": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Gostaria de mapear os `standings` para minha viewModel:

```
public class CompetitionViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Posição")]
    public int Position { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vitórias")]
    public int Won { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Empates")]
    public int Draw { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Derrotas")]
    public int Lost { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pontos")]
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

E aqui eu Deserializei o Objeto:

```
public class ApplicationCompetition
{
    public Competition Competition { get; set; }

    public Season Season { get; set; }

    public List<Standings> Standings { get; set; }
}

public class Competition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Area Area { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Plan { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class Area
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Season
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public int CurrentMatchday { get; set; }

    public string Winner { get; set; }
}

public class Standings
{
    public string Stage { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public string Group { get; set; }

    public List<Table> Table { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    public int Position { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public int PlayedGames { get; set; }

    public int Won { get; set; }

    public int Draw { get; set; }

    public int Lost { get; set; }

    public int Points { get; set; }

    public int GoalsFor { get; set; }

    public int GoalsAgainst { get; set; }

    public int GoalDifference { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string CrestUrl { get; set; }
}
```

A parte de desarilizar o objeto está tudo correto, mas o meu problema é na hora de mapear esse objeto desarilizado para a minha viewModel:

```
_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CompetitionViewModel>>(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApplicationCompetition>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result));
```

É Nessa parte que estou me batendo para conseguir mapear o objeto, não sei como faço para mapear a lista de `standings`, pegando o `name` que está dentro de team:

```
public MappingProfile()
{
    CreateMap<ApplicationCompetition, CompetitionViewModel>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Position, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Standings[0].Table[0].Position));
 }
```

Por exemplo, eu preciso mapear o `standings` => `team` => `name`, para o atributo `Name`, na minha ViewModel.

Esse é o meu Objeto, preciso criar a ViewModel, apeanas com o dados dentro da `Table`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: dado que standings e table são listas, porque ele resultaria em só um nome e não n nomes?

Comment: Sugiro copiar o json e colar especial json como classe no visual studio. assim ele irá erar a classe exata que você precisa, para serializar e desserializar.